# Update Currently Running Batch Script

Tags: batch-file, updates

Playing around with my Batch script again. It was brought to my attention that my update routine was not working correctly. Iteration 1 would result in the running script being deleted and not copying the new version from a folder I had selected. Iteration 2 now deletes the old script and copies the new script but with each line of code I change I end up with the currently running script closing, and the new updated script not launching.

Here's a snippet of the Update routine:

```
:Options
REM I'll set the variable here to what is set elsewhere in the script.
SET VERSION=Version 1.7
CLS
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO %VERSION%
ECHO. 
ECHO. 
ECHO ==================== OPTIONS =====================
ECHO.
ECHO     1. Update Script WIP
ECHO     2. Install entire script to Statup Folder
ECHO     3. Install individual items for auto-launch
ECHO     4. Install Windows Logout feature
ECHO     5. Uninstall
ECHO     6. Change Colors
ECHO     7. Changelog
ECHO.
ECHO =======PRESS 'Q' TO QUIT OR 'B' TO GO BACK========
ECHO.

SET OPTION=
SET /P OPTION=Select an Option:
IF /I '%OPTION%'=='1' GOTO Update
IF /I '%OPTION%'=='2' GOTO Install
IF /I '%OPTION%'=='3' GOTO I_Install
IF /I '%OPTION%'=='4' GOTO I_Logout
IF /I '%OPTION%'=='5' GOTO Uinstall
IF /I '%OPTION%'=='6' GOTO Colors
IF /I '%OPTION%'=='7' GOTO Changelog
IF /I '%OPTION%'=='q' GOTO quit
IF /I '%OPTION%'=='quit' GOTO quit
IF /I '%OPTION%'=='b' GOTO menu
IF /I '%OPTION%'=='back' GOTO menu

ECHO.
ECHO ============INVALID INPUT============
ECHO Please select a number
ECHO or select 'Q' or 'B'.
ECHO ======PRESS ANY KEY TO CONTINUE======

PAUSE > NUL
GOTO Options

:Update
ECHO.
IF EXIST "%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\Shortcut Browser *.bat" (
  GOTO Update_1
  ) ELSE (
    ECHO You have not installed the script yet. Please install the script first.
  )    
PAUSE
GOTO Options

:Update_1
  IF EXIST "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Temp\Update.bat" (
    GOTO Update_2
  )  ELSE  (
REM Here the main script writes an update script to a batch file
     ECHO DEL "%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\Shortcut Browser *.bat" > "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Temp\Update.bat"
REM I replaced the original file location with one on the desktop. The original location was on a network drive, location is confidential.
     ECHO COPY "%userprofile\Desktop\Shortcut Browser *.bat" "%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup" >> "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Temp\Update.bat"
     ECHO CALL "%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\Shortcut Browser *.bat" >> "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Temp\Update.bat"
     ECHO EXIT >> "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Temp\Update.bat"
  )
GOTO Update_2

REM Here the main script calls upon the update script
:Update_2
  CALL "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Temp\Update.bat"
REM The script seems to hang here. Either both the scripts will remain open or close or a combination depending on where CALL and START were used.
  PAUSE
GOTO Options
```

I saw elsewhere I could have used the FC command. I didn't know about it until troubleshooting this problem. I've gotten this far and I feel I'm just missing some small trick to get the new updated script to launch.

If you need any more info let me know. I think I covered everything.

Comment: Two things, immediately stand out, the main one being both instances of `\Shortcut Browser *.bat" (` should be `\Shortcut Browser" *.bat (`. The other being that using `%temp%` or `%tmp%` is usually the default same as `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Temp`, so unless you're working on not default, altered, systems, would be preferable.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know there was an environment variable for the the temp folder. The `\Shortcut Browser *.bat" (` is the file name. It's called "Shortcut Browser v1.7". The update folder I want to pull from will always have 1 batch script in it, that latest version. Right now the update folder contains "Shortcut Browser v1.8" and the startup folder contains the v1.7 script. I want to update to v1.8 and to consecutive versions in the future. I thought using a wildcard was the best solution at the time.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification regarding the filename, although I'm wondering now why, you you didn't use, `\Shortcut Browser v*.bat" (`, it seems very slightly more robust and greatly more understandable. _Without seeing more, I'm perplexed as to how why you haven't developed an auto incrementing routine using the known version numbering sequence._

Comment: I'm new to Batch. And other than that all I've bothered to learn is basics in Lua. I'm writing Batch for work use to make the job a little more bearable. Though in my line of work free time is plenty but frequently interrupted. Focus is not my forte. Ultimately it's help me pass the time and to help me learn something useful to a degree. This is the first Batch script I've put effort into. I didn't see any reason to adjust `\Shortcut Browser *.bat" (` as it already worked in my code. I understand if I wanted to use the numerical value of that wildcard in code it would eventually have to change

Comment: I would suggest it both crazy and unlikely that each version wouldn't be prefixed with **`v`** though, why ignore a potentially more robust search mask? _TBF, I find having absolute choice over file naming, more especially when using the outdated `.bat` extension, that naming them using spaces to be crazy too!_

Comment: Well. I'm no professional. Who knows maybe I'll get out of this place and do something amazing for myself. But I'm enjoying it here. Co-workers seem to enjoy my knowledge of computers at least. Here's the script in its entirety. I hope I obfuscated it enough to hide some of the sensitive information [Shortcut Browser v1.7](https://pastebin.com/GczRXu2D)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
TITLE Super Script 5000

:Options
REM I'll set the variable here to what is set elsewhere in the script.
SET VERSION=Version 1.7
CLS
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO %VERSION%
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO ==================== OPTIONS =====================
ECHO.
ECHO     1. Update Script WIP
ECHO     2. Install entire script to Statup Folder
ECHO     3. Install individual items for auto-launch
ECHO     4. Install Windows Logout feature
ECHO     5. Uninstall
ECHO     6. Change Colors
ECHO     7. Changelog
ECHO.
ECHO =======PRESS 'Q' TO QUIT OR 'B' TO GO BACK========
ECHO.

SET "OPTION="
SET /P "OPTION=Select an Option: "
IF /I "%OPTION%"=="1" GOTO Update
IF /I "%OPTION%"=="2" GOTO Install
IF /I "%OPTION%"=="3" GOTO I_Install
IF /I "%OPTION%"=="4" GOTO I_Logout
IF /I "%OPTION%"=="5" GOTO Uinstall
IF /I "%OPTION%"=="6" GOTO Colors
IF /I "%OPTION%"=="7" GOTO Changelog
IF /I "%OPTION%"=="q" GOTO quit
IF /I "%OPTION%"=="quit" GOTO quit
IF /I "%OPTION%"=="b" GOTO menu
IF /I "%OPTION%"=="back" GOTO menu

ECHO.
ECHO ============INVALID INPUT============
ECHO Please select a number
ECHO or select 'Q' or 'B'.
ECHO ======PRESS ANY KEY TO CONTINUE======

PAUSE > NUL
GOTO Options

:Update
  ECHO.
  IF EXIST "%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\Shortcut Browser *.bat" (
    GOTO Update_1
  ) ELSE (
    ECHO You have not installed the script yet. Please install the script first.
  )
  PAUSE
GOTO Options

:Update_1
  IF EXIST "%tmp%\update.bat" (
    2>NUL DEL "%tmp%\update.bat" || GOTO Options
  )

  SETLOCAL

  FOR %%A IN (
    "%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\Shortcut Browser *.bat"
  ) DO (
    SET "old_version=%%~A"
    SET "old_dir=%%~dpA"
    SET "old_file=%%~nxA"
  )

  FOR %%A IN (
    "%userprofile%\Desktop\Shortcut Browser *.bat"
  ) DO (
    SET "new_version=%%~A"
    SET "new_dir=%%~dpA"
    SET "new_file=%%~nxA"
  )

  IF NOT DEFINED old_version (
    ENDLOCAL
    GOTO Options
  ) ELSE IF NOT DEFINED new_version (
    ENDLOCAL
    GOTO Options
  )

  (
    ECHO @ECHO OFF
    ECHO SETLOCAL
    ECHO.
    ECHO ECHO Update and restarting...
    ECHO ^>NUL PING localhost -n 3
    ECHO.
    ECHO SET "old_version=%old_version%"
    ECHO SET "new_version=%new_version%"
    ECHO SET "updated_version=%old_dir%\%new_file%"
    ECHO.
    ECHO CALL :log /clear_log
    ECHO.
    ECHO IF NOT EXIST "%%new_version%%" (
    ECHO   CALL :log ERROR: Not exist "%%new_version%%".
    ECHO   EXIT /B 1
    ECHO ^)
    ECHO.
    ECHO CALL :log Move old_version to old_version.bak.
    ECHO MOVE "%%old_version%%" "%%old_version%%.bak" ^|^| (
    ECHO   CALL :log ERROR: Move failed to backup old version.
    ECHO   EXIT /B 2
    ECHO ^)
    ECHO.
    ECHO CALL :log Copy new_version to old_version.
    ECHO COPY "%%new_version%%" "%%appdata%%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\" ^|^| (
    ECHO   CALL :log ERROR: Copy failed. Restore old version.
    ECHO   MOVE "%%old_version%%.bak" "%%old_version%%" ^|^| (
    ECHO     CALL :log ERROR: Restore old version failed.
    ECHO     EXIT /B 3
    ECHO   ^)
    ECHO   EXIT /B 4
    ECHO ^)
    ECHO.
    ECHO CALL :log Delete old_version.bak.
    ECHO DEL "%%old_version%%.bak" ^|^| (
    ECHO   CALL :log WARNING: Delete backup file failed.
    ECHO ^)
    ECHO.
    ECHO IF NOT EXIST "%%updated_version%%" (
    ECHO   CALL :log ERROR: Not exist: "%%updated_version%%"
    ECHO   EXIT /B 5
    ECHO ^)
    ECHO.
    ECHO ENDLOCAL
    ECHO.
    ECHO ECHO Ready to restart updated version
    ECHO PAUSE
    ECHO CALL "%old_dir%\%new_file%"
    ECHO EXIT /B
    ECHO.
    ECHO :log
    ECHO   SETLOCAL
    ECHO   SET "log=%%tmp%%\update.log"
    ECHO   IF /I "%%~1"=="/clear_log" TYPE NUL ^> "%%log%%" ^& EXIT /B
    ECHO   IF /I "%%~1"=="/delete_log" 2^>NUL DEL "%%log%%" ^& EXIT /B
    ECHO   SET args=%%*
    ECHO   IF NOT DEFINED args EXIT /B
    ECHO   ECHO %%*
    ECHO   ^>^> "%%log%%" ECHO %%*
    ECHO EXIT /B
  ) > "%tmp%\update.bat"
  ENDLOCAL

  START "Super Script 5000" "cmd /c "%tmp%\update.bat""
EXIT

:Quit
```

Tested on a *Win7 VM*. The script needs to restart on update else
weird issues may occur. CMD does not like scripts changing as it
is reading and interpreting them. Even reusing the same console
using `START` with `/B` may cause key input issues.

`update.bat` is overwritten every update as it stores absolute paths
so each update will be different paths with the filenames changing.
Using a wildcard with `CALL` may not work too well otherwise.

`update.bat` moves the old version to a .bak file, copies the new
version and if successful, deletes the .bak file, else moves the
.bak file to the old version. This is just to ensure a current
version always exists even if the update fails.

Changed quotes in `:Options` label from `'` to `"`. Quotes are not
interchangeable like some other languages. Example: `"%OPTION%"`
will work if contains a space though `'%OPTION%'` may cause error.

I notice no `SETLOCAL` at the top of your full script. Advise you add
it unless you have a good reason not to.

I merged labels `:Update_1` and `:Update_2` into one.

Perhaps adjust `Ping localhost -n` number if more or less time is
needed.

Look at the `%tmp%\update.log` if a problem happens. Though expect
the errors to show in the console as the label `:log` in
`update.bat` echoes to console and writes to the log.

Comment: I have `SETLOCAL` at the beginning of my script and `ENDLOCAL` at exit points of the script now. Thanks for the more robust and idiot proof edit. But the full script still isn't restarting after updating. It seems with your edit the update script runs, waits, then deletes and moves the new version into `...\Startup\`. After the new version is copied in the update script closes and doesn't launch the new full script. This is the problem I was looking to solve. I hope I haven't missed anything. Thank you regardless.

Comment: I may have solved issues with more code handling in the created `update.bat`. It also outputs more info to console and to a log file so hopefully you know if and what issues occur. With `ENDLOCAL`, exiting a *called* label or exiting a script usually implies `ENDLOCAL`.

Comment: Awesome, I'll play around wit it some more when I have time.